# npm not included in ASP.NET Core Web Application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to learn ASP.NET Core 1.0, and I am creating a ASP.NET Core project with the "Web Application" template, but I am seeing a discrepancy with what I am expecting. I was under the impression that npm and gulp were included in the project as the [documentation](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/client-side/using-gulp.html) states:

> The template also includes Node Package Manager (npm) and Gulp, making it easier to add bundling and minification to a project.

And also:

> When you create a new web project using ASP.NET Core Web Application template, Visual Studio includes the Gulp.js npm package, the gulpfile.js file, and a set of Gulp dependencies.

However, I am not seeing npm as a package management option, nor am I seeing any files related to npm or Gulp. I do, however, see Bower options.

I am using Microsoft .NET Core Tools 1.0.0 (Preview 2).

Comment: Are you using the empty sub-template?

Comment: No, I am using Web Application template.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

gulp/grunt/npm is still supported but was removed from the default project template in the preview tooling that shipped with ASP.NET Core RTM

I think you can just manually add a package.json file and a gulpfile.js and makes some edits in the scripts section of project.json in the web app to get back in business as it was in RC2

the default template uses a new [bundler minifier](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/aspnetmonsters/ASPNET-Monsters-Episode-43-Hello-Bundler-Minifier-with-Mads-Kristensen)

there was also discussion about it in [community standup](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p6NUkeTVsGE&feature=youtu.be) if you want to learn the reasoning behind the changes

Comment: Thanks. Do you know if it's documented anywhere?

Comment: what do you mean, how to manually setup gulp/grunt/npm in a new project? or how to use the new bundler/minifier included in the latest project template?

Comment: I meant more along the lines of a change log of it being removed out of the box or an announcement along with the reasoning. Because the current documentation is still saying it's included and those files are generated, from the link in my question. The only place I've seen it being removed or discussion related to it is in that video you linked.

Comment: there are still quite a few things in the docs that are not up to date with RTM, it is mentioned in the Release Notes and Known Issues section here https://github.com/aspnet/Tooling and in the notes from the community standup https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/06/22/notes-from-the-asp-net-community-standup-june-21-2016/

Comment: just learned that you can right click the bundleconfig.json file in vs 2015 and choose Bundler & Minifier > Convert To gulp. that creates a gulp file for you but doesn't update the scripts section of project.json